# Vite build gives 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, vite

I am new to [vite](https://vitejs.dev/), I did install, wrote some code, did *npm run dev* and *npm run build*.

Everything went fine until uploading to my server.

index.html:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.a673cca3.js"></script>
```

Running from live server, I get these errors

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED index.4293b7ae.css:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND index.a673cca3.js
```

The filenames are correct and they are where are suposed to be.

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that all files on the public directory will resolve to the root. I was uploading to a directory (www. whatever.com/someproject/), so the solution was to specify the correct path on the vite.config.js

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
    base: '/someproject/'
}
 
// if uploading to a subdomain it is ok to no specify any dir:
export default {
    base: '/'
}

// using a relative path will work on any dir:
export default {
    base: './'
}
```